# sam local start-api gives error while testing SAM application in local

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, docker, aws-sam-cli

Hi i have a sam application which one lambda function and can be invoked from rest endpoint which is working as expected but when i try to test the sam application locally using sam local start-lambda or sam local start-api or sam local invoke  i get the error as  :

```
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Users\divyanayan.awasthi\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\docker\transport\npipeconn.py", line 31, in connect
    sock.connect(self.npipe_path)
  File "C:\Users\divyanayan.awasthi\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\docker\transport\npipesocket.py", line 22, in wrapped
    return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\divyanayan.awasthi\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\docker\transport\npipesocket.py", line 50, in connect
    win32pipe.WaitNamedPipe(address, self._timeout)
pywintypes.error: (2, 'WaitNamedPipe', 'The system cannot find the file specified.')
```

Sam version used

```
SAM CLI, version 0.7.0
```

Is this because i dont have a docker running in my local or some other configuration  is required .i have one .py class and template.yml file for SAM application.

Answer (score 3):

Yes we need to install docker locally then sam local works as expected .if you are running sam local on windows then there might a problem to install docker installer as it needs Windows 10 Pro or enterpise version to install.

In case you dont have the above windows configuration  then install docker toolbox

https://docs.docker.com/toolbox/toolbox_install_windows/